# Splitting strings

Tags: perl

I have string like this:

```
in.a+in.b=in.c
```

I want to put the characters that are next to the dot (i.e., `a` and `b`) on the left-hand side in one list and the other character, which is on the right-hand side (i.e., `c`) in another list. Can you please help me with the code?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string="in.a+in.b=in.c";
my @chars=split("=",$string);
print "First: @chars";
```

*Note:* the "equal to" operator will be there, but any number of characters can be there on the left-hand or right-hand side. So I just want to put the characters that are next to the `.` in one list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my ($lhs, $rhs) = split(/=/, $string);
my @lhs_leaves = $lhs =~ /\.(\w+)/g;
my @rhs_leaves = $rhs =~ /\.(\w+)/g;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a regex to extract the strings from the left and right hand sides.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $string = 'in.a+in.b=in.c';

my ($lhs, $rhs) = split /=/, $string;
my @left  = $lhs =~ /\.(\w+)/g;
my @right = $rhs =~ /\.(\w+)/g;

print "Left: @left.\nRight: @right.\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my $string = "in.a+in.b=in.c";
my @parts = map { [ /\.(\w+)/g ] } split(/=/, $string);
```

The bits on the left-hand side will be in `$parts[0]`, and the bits on the right-hand side will be in `$parts[1]`. Here's a [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) representation of the result:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'a',
            'b'
          ],
          [
            'c'
          ]
        ];
```

And here's a usage example:

```
print "Left-hand side: @{$parts[0]}\n";
print "Right-hand side: @{$parts[1]}\n";
```

Output:

```
Left-hand side: a b
Right-hand side: c
```